# Excel VBA - Weekday and/or datediff function not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below which is supposed to parse a column with dates/times and advise (by highlighting) if the value is older than 24 hours ago as of 6:30am on the current day.  If the day is Monday, it is supposed to look back 72 hours (since Saturday and Sunday are not work days) and advise if the value is older than 72 hours as of 6:30am.

Something is amiss as it is not highlighting values that are breaching the 24 hours threshold, but I don't know what it is.

```
'Highlight breached tickets
Dim updateRange As Range, updateCell As Range
Set updateRange = Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) Then
    For Each updateCell In updateRange
        If DateDiff("h", CDate(updateCell.Value), CDate(Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")) + TimeSerial(6, 30, 0)) > 72 Then
            updateCell.Interior.Color = 13311
            updateCell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = 13311
        End If
    Next updateCell
Else
    For Each updateCell In updateRange
        If DateDiff("h", CDate(updateCell.Value), CDate(Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")) + TimeSerial(6, 30, 0)) > 24 Then
            updateCell.Interior.Color = 13311
            updateCell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = 13311
        End If
    Next updateCell
End If
```

Comment: The `Weekday()` function returns a Variant (Integer), not a Boolean. You need to provide a comparison value. `If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = vbMonday Then ...`

Comment: Ah yes.  That fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said you need to test `Weekday` against something as it doesn't return a `Boolean` value. However, thought I'd add this as you could re-write your code so you don't repeat yourself as nearly all of it is doing exactly the same

```
'Highlight breached tickets
Dim updateRange As Range, updateCell As Range
Dim TimeDiff As Long
Set updateRange = Range("D2:D" & Lastrow)

TimeDiff = IIf(Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 1, 72, 40)

For Each updateCell In updateRange
    If DateDiff("h", CDate(updateCell.Value), CDate(Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")) + TimeSerial(6, 30, 0)) > TimeDiff Then
        updateCell.Interior.Color = 13311
        updateCell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = 13311
    End If
Next updateCell
```

Writing it this way makes it much easier to maintain

***Update after comments***
To modify this to cope with other days as well, the simplest (and easiest to read) would be to change the `TimeDiff =` line and using a `Select Case` statement to set the value

```
'Highlight breached tickets
Dim updateRange As Range, updateCell As Range
Dim TimeDiff As Long
Set updateRange = Range("D2:D" & Lastrow)

Select Case Weekday(Date, vbMonday)
    ' Monday
    Case 1
        TimeDiff = 72
    ' Tuesday
    Case 2
        TimeDiff = 96
    ' Any other day
    Case Else
        TimeDiff = 40
End Select

For Each updateCell In updateRange
    If DateDiff("h", CDate(updateCell.Value), CDate(Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy")) + TimeSerial(6, 30, 0)) > TimeDiff Then
        updateCell.Interior.Color = 13311
        updateCell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = 13311
    End If
Next updateCell
```

Comment: I tried to edit this code to add a snippet in for Tuesday (to be used if the script was run on Tuesday because there was no work on Monday).  I thought it was as simple as changing the variable from TimeDiff to something else, changing vbMonday to vbTuesday, and changing the 1, 72, 40 to 1, 96, 40.  I was wrong, because it didn't work, and I cannot get it to work.  What am I missing?

Comment: @sbagnato Please have a look at the update to my answer

Comment: So Case 1 would be if I was running this on a Monday morning, it would highlight cells 72 hours and older, based on 6:30am.  So Case 2, would timeDiff then be 96?  And ect for the rest of the days of the week?

Comment: Yes if you wanted to get everything from Monday, Sunday and Saturday. Sorry, used a random number in my example for Tuesday

Comment: No worries.  And just to make sure I have my understanding correct before I make changes, since it is set to update the cell color, it would update cell colors of cells with values that are 72:01 and older, correct?

Comment: I'd test it on your data to make sure but yes it should do.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Kostas K. in the comments, `Weekday()` returns an `Integer` number from 1 to 7, which is always evaluated to a `True` boolean - [MSDN Weekday](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634550.aspx)!

However, if you use `If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = vbMonday` most probably you will get a `False` if the today is Monday.

That is because the default day of the beginning of the Weekday is Sunday. And you are changing it to Monday. And from the contrary, `vbMonday` is always evaluated to `2` (write `?vbMonday` at the immediate window)

Anyhow, it is probably a bit easier to see it than to explain it. Today it is Friday (TGIF). Thus, simply run the following code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print Weekday(Date) = vbFriday            'True
    Debug.Print Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = vbFriday  'False
End Sub
```